# How to force the closing of an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, exit, close-application

I have an electron app that loads the URL of the web version of the app.
However I cannot close the application by clicking in the X button and I dont have access to the webapp.
I have tried this:

```
let count = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length; 
///returns 1, so there is only 1 window)
                        
window.onbeforeunload=function(e){
    e.returnValue=undefined;
    return undefined;
}
window.close();
app.quit();
```

Nothing happens.

`app.exit(0)` works, but I dont want to use it. Is there a way I can close the app with `window.close` and `app.quit`?

EDIT:
The problem are those global beforeunload events. If i click remove in the devtools I am able to close the app.
[image]

Also this `let names= window.eventNames();`returns an array that does not have any **beforeunload** events

Comment: Wait, are you using window global (renderer) inside electron (main) code?

Comment: can you just post the repo link?

Comment: I am creating a BrowserWindow and then loading a url in that window.
I cant post the link :(

Comment: I'm no JavaScript hero but I think using `window` as a variable name is a "bad idea".

Answer (score 1):

In the file where you created the BrowserWindow, you can attach an event to the 'close' handler for the window. For Electron, this is usually main.js.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let mainWindow = null;
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
       //options here
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL([url here]);

    //attach event handler here
    mainWindow.on("close", () => {
       mainWindow = null;
       app.quit();
    });
});
```

For good measure, in the case that you may have more than one window, place this in your main.js file.

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
     if(process.platform !== "darwin")
         app.quit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the **BrowserWindow** object reference. Then listen for a 'closed' event and dereference it:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let win; // = new BrowserWindow();

win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null
})
```

After dereference, it's all simple, just listen for 'window-all-closed' event on **app**:

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
})
```